# Set non-Latin alphabet for SQL on C# side

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, collation

The problem is when user insert `non-Latin` word to database, if collation not set to that `alphabet`, the word comes like '`?????`' But if user insert word like `N'word'` or I select it like `N'word'` there is no problem.
I use `hastable function` on `C#` side so is there any solution for use N'word' format automaticly or must I use N before text everytime I call function?
I already use `NVARCHAR` format by the way.

The simple way to ask;
I don't want to use `N'word'` format every time when I select item from database.
Is there any trigger, stored procedure or function for add automaticly N before text I select.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the `N'word'` format at all, you should use parameters. When you concatenate values into a string to create a query, it's wide open to SQL injection attacks unless you managage to escape all input exactly right.

Put parameters in the query and add the values to the `Parameters` collection of the command. Example:

```
string query = "select Id from Persons where Name = @Name";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection)) {

  cmd.Parameters.Add('@Name', SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).value = name;

  using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
      ...
    }
  }

}
```

Using unicode types like `NVarChar` for the parameter ensures that the parameter value is sent as unicode, equivalent to the `N'word'` format.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use some sort of ORM. Dapper is a lightweight ORM:
https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

It will solve your problems with parameter passing if this is the troubles you are having

Comment: Databases and tables are already created and too big to change something. So I think I can't use the ORM, but thank you.

Comment: Using ORM doesn't affect database. Alternativly use `SqlCommand` as Guffa suggested. The way You're doing it is wrong in many ways